# mongodb service in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mongodb in php. 
There's no problem if mongodb is start in shell with *mongod* command.

```
new Mongo("mongodb://".$_host.":".$_port,true)
```

But when i start mongodb server as a service, i can connect with the *mongo* command, but i cant connect in php.

```
new Mongo("mongodb://".$_host.":".$_port,true)
```

Is there any other arguments? 
I'm using the last version of mongodb and the last version of php.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What operating system are you running? Did you check service configuration files?

Comment: I've always just done `$mongo=new Mongo();` and use the default settings. Then again, I've never had to access a db on another host/port.

Comment: I'm on windows 7, and i have checked the service configuration files, i found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer and comment, i fix it.

The problem was in the service  command line , i use this command

```
"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod" --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --logpath "C:\data\db\mongodb.log" --logappend --dbpath "C:\data\db" --port 27100 --install
```

instead of

```
"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod" --bind_ip myIPadress --logpath "C:\data\db\mongodb.log" --logappend --dbpath "C:\data\db" --port 27100 --install
```

In the php code `new Mongo("mongodb://".$_host.":".$_port,true)` , $host = myIPadress

That why it was working in command line and not in the php code, it must be the same IPadress, don't use localhost or something like that if you don't use a default `new Mongo()`

Answer (score 0):

What are your command line parameters for the MongoDB service?  Is it possible that you've specified a different configuration than what you get by default when manually running mongod? What parameters did you use to install MongoDB as a service?

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem i fix it and explain it in the answer.